# Find out if a collection was populated by bulk collect

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-type

I created an oracle Object Type like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DFBOWNER."RPT_WIRE_IMPORT_ROWTYPE" AS OBJECT

(
REC_VALUE_DATE   DATE
)
/
```

And then a collection based on this type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DFBOWNER."RPT_WIRE_IMPORT_TABLETYPE" IS TABLE OF RPT_WIRE_IMPORT_RowType;
/
```

Now I populate the collection using oracle bulk collect into syntax inside a procedure.
So now i want to  test if the collection actually got populated, and i am not sure how to do it.
I tried looking it up:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#autoId17 but I am not able to find what I need.

I also have another question. When the procedure bulk collects data into collections, does the data in the collection become permanent as in a table? Or is it semi-permanent...i.e. only lives for the session...as in a temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for the `COUNT` method, i.e.

```
DECLARE
  l_local_collection dbfowner.rpt_wire_import_tabletype;
BEGIN
  SELECT sysdate + level
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_local_collection
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 10;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'l_local_collection contains ' || 
                           l_local_collection.count || 
                           ' elements.' );
END;
```

Like any local variable, `l_local_collection` will have the scope of the block in which it is declared.  The data is stored in the PGA for the session.  The data in a collection is not permanent.

You can select from the local collection

```
SQL> create type some_object as object (
  2    rec_value_date date
  3  );
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create type some_coll
  2      as table of some_object;
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_local_collection some_coll;
  3  begin
  4    select some_object( sysdate + numtodsinterval( level, 'day' ) )
  5      bulk collect into l_local_collection
  6      from dual
  7   connect by level <= 10;
  8    for x in (select * from table( l_local_collection ))
  9    loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line( x.rec_value_date );
 11    end loop;
 12* end;
SQL> /
20-AUG-12
21-AUG-12
22-AUG-12
23-AUG-12
24-AUG-12
25-AUG-12
26-AUG-12
27-AUG-12
28-AUG-12
29-AUG-12

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

but it generally doesn't make sense to go through the effort of pulling all the data from the SQL VM into the PL/SQL VM only to then pass all of the data back to the SQL VM in order to issue the `SELECT` statement.  It would generally make more sense to just keep the data in SQL or to define a pipelined table function to return the data.

If you merely want to iterate over the elements in the collection

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_local_collection some_coll;
  3  begin
  4    select some_object( sysdate + numtodsinterval( level, 'day' ) )
  5      bulk collect into l_local_collection
  6      from dual
  7   connect by level <= 10;
  8    for i in 1 .. l_local_collection.count
  9    loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line( l_local_collection(i).rec_value_date );
 11    end loop;
 12* end;
SQL> /
20-AUG-12
21-AUG-12
22-AUG-12
23-AUG-12
24-AUG-12
25-AUG-12
26-AUG-12
27-AUG-12
28-AUG-12
29-AUG-12

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It would make much more sense to iterate over the elements in the collection, which keeps everything in PL/SQL, than to `SELECT` from the collection, which forces all the data back into the SQL VM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Justin.  I am basically looking for to do: select * from l_local_collection and expecting a record set in return. Is this possible?

Comment: @Kaushik - I updated my answer.  It is possible to do so but generally not advisable.

Comment: For <<do something>> , I tried: dbms_output.put_line(l_local_collection.col_name_in_collection). It says :PLS00302. col_name_in_collection must be declared. But the collection has already been created wit hte relevant column(s)

Comment: Thank you very much. appreciate your attention to detail.